# Convert Ruby String to Integer with default value

Tags: ruby, integer, type-conversion

Is there a Ruby method that takes a string and a default value and converts it to integer if the string represents integer or returns the default value otherwise?

**update**
I think the following answer is preferable:

```
class String
  def try_to_i(default = nil)
    /^\d+$/ === self ? to_i : default
  end
end
```

Here is evidence why you should avoid exceptions:

```
> def time; t = Time.now; yield; Time.now - t end

> time { 1000000.times { |i| ('_' << i.to_s) =~ /\d+/ } }
=> 1.3491532 
> time { 1000000.times { |i| Integer.new('_' << i.to_s) rescue nil } }
=> 27.190596426
```

Comment: What do you mean by "contains integer"?

Comment: `"premature optimization is the root of all evil"` - Donald Knuth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to code that yourself, possibly using a regular expression to check the string:

```
def try_to_i(str, default = nil)
  str =~ /^-?\d+$/ ? str.to_i : default
end
```

Answer (score 8):

There's `#to_i` and `Integer()` to convert. The first has a default of
0, the second one raises an ArgumentError.

```
class String
  def to_integer(default)
    Integer(self)
  rescue ArgumentError
    default
  end
end
```

Comment: I think using exceptions for normal use cases is too high performance overhead

Comment: I have to agree that this is the more elegant solution and should be accepted. I only didn't suggest this because I didn't know about `Integer()`. @Alexey: The overhead of using a regex for the job is even more problematic.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
int_value = (stringVar.match(/^(\d+)$/) && $1.to_i) || default_value
```

That will see if the string is composed entirely of digits, and if so, convert to int, or return your default value.

Comment: Ruby has `?:`, so why use the unreliable `&& ... || ...` idiom?

Comment: IMO, it seems more conceptually sound to bundle the integer case into a parenthetical block, rather than use the ternary operator. Also, how is &&/|| unreliable? Sure, there's the issue of precedence if you switch between their written-word equivalent operators (or/and), but consistent use eliminates that. All that said, it's up to you - if ternary suits your style, go for it.

Comment: I meant the fact that you always have to think twice if the part between `&&` and `||` can become `false` or `nil`, in which case it's not equivalent to the conditional operator or an `if .. then .. else`. In this case it's okay because `to_i` always returns an integer value. BTW, the parentheses are not needed in your example.